# How to display 2D graphics in pangolin with panel

Tags: c++, opengl, window, opengl-compat

I can't figure out how to use pangolin to display 2D openGL graphics.

I'm am in internship in the research department of a school.
I am very novice at OpenGl and Pangolin.
I'm trying to add a monitoring window to an open_source program so that it is more user-friendly. This program is [ORB_SLAM2](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2), and it already uses [pangolin](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin) as an openGL display manager. It has already some windows opening with panels and 3d openGL displays like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYtKi.png)by this piece of code

```
void Viewer::Run()
{
    //...

    pangolin::CreateWindowAndBind("ORB-SLAM2: Map Viewer",1024,768);

    // 3D Mouse handler requires depth testing to be enabled
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Issue specific OpenGl we might need
    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    pangolin::CreatePanel("menu").SetBounds(0.0,1.0,0.0,pangolin::Attach::Pix(175));
        // ... define elements of the menu (not important)
    // Define Camera Render Object (for view / scene browsing)
    pangolin::OpenGlRenderState s_cam( 
 pangolin::ProjectionMatrix(1024,768,mViewpointF,mViewpointF,512,389,0.1,1000),
pangolin::ModelViewLookAt(mViewpointX,mViewpointY,mViewpointZ, 0,0,0,0.0,-1.0, 0.0));

    // Add named OpenGL viewport to window and provide 3D Handler
    pangolin::View& d_cam = pangolin::CreateDisplay()
            .SetBounds(0.0, 1.0, pangolin::Attach::Pix(175), 1.0, -1024.0f/768.0f)
            .SetHandler(new pangolin::Handler3D(s_cam));

    pangolin::OpenGlMatrix Twc;
    Twc.SetIdentity();
        //...

    while(1)
    {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            mpMapDrawer->GetCurrentOpenGLCameraMatrix(Twc);

            //...

            d_cam.Activate(s_cam);
            glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
            mpMapDrawer->DrawCurrentCamera(Twc);
            if(menuShowKeyFrames || menuShowGraph)
                mpMapDrawer->DrawKeyFrames(menuShowKeyFrames,menuShowGraph);
            if(menuShowPoints)
                mpMapDrawer->DrawMapPoints();

            pangolin::FinishFrame();
                        //...
       }
```

So I tried to copy that and remove the 3D handling part of it like this

```
void Monitor::Run()
{
    //...

    pangolin::CreateWindowAndBind("ORB-SLAM2: Monitoring",1024,768);

    // Issue specific OpenGl we might need
    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    pangolin::View& menu = pangolin::CreatePanel("vars").SetBounds(0.0,1.0,0.0,pangolin::Attach::Pix(175));
    //...
    // Add named OpenGL viewport to window

    pangolin::View& graph = pangolin::CreateDisplay()
            .SetBounds(0.0, 1.0, pangolin::Attach::Pix(175), 1.0, 1024.0f/768.0f);
    while (1){
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        graph.Activate();
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
// 2D Basic test shape
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor3f(0.4f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
            glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.8f);
            glVertex2f(-0.8f, -0.8f);
            glVertex2f(0.8f, -0.8f);
            glVertex2f(0.8f, 0.8f); glEnd();
        pangolin::FinishFrame();
    }
}
```

But The 2D Shape isn't apearing, it only shows the background color

I tried the followings:

- Removing the Panel: it makes the shape appear but I want to keep the panel.
- Changing zorders of the menu and the shape in both orders, didn't change anything
- Not enclosing it in an infinite while loop: Both panel and shape appeared but obviously it is a static image. But it appears the render works the first call of FinishFrame() and then it doesn't anymore.

And other stuffs but i can't list it all here.

I'm wandering if it is because I didn't create OpenGlRenderState Object, But I don't understand why I would need it for 2D Rendering from my understanding of OpenGL and Pangolin.

I hope you guys can help me.